# Initialize enum c++

Tags: c++, enums

I create an enum called `Types`:

```
enum  Types {Int,Double,String};
```

When I create an object and initialize it with one of the enum allowed values I get the following error: "Error: type name is not allowed".

```
Types ty = Types.Double;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexTheo: That is clearly dependent on what you are actually trying to achieve? Enums are great for what is meant for, enumerating something enumerable, e.g `enum Colours { red, green, blue };` or `enum Weekdays { monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday };`

Comment: @AlexTheo, The usage is for virtual method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++, there are two different types of enumerations - scoped and unscoped ones (the former was introduced with C++11). For unscoped ones the names of the enumerators are directly introduced into the enclosing scope.

> **N3337 §7.2/10**
>
> Each *enum-name* and each unscoped *enumerator* is declared in the
>   scope that immediately contains the *enum-specifier*. Each scoped
>   *enumerator* is declared in the scope of the enumeration. These names obey the scope rules defined for all names in (3.3) and (3.4).

Your enumeration is unscoped, therefore it suffices to write

```
Types ty = Double;
```

For scoped enumerations, as the name suggests, the enumerators are declared in the enumeration scope and have to be qualified with the enumeration-name:

```
enum class ScopedTypes {Int,Double,String}; 
enum UnscopedTypes     {Int,Double,String}; 

ScopedTypes a = ScopedTypes::Double;
//ScopedTypes b = Double; // error

UnscopedTypes c = UnscopedTypes::Double;
UnscopedTypes d = Double;
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try to use the code of your `ScopedTypes` enum I get the error: `expected either a difinition or a tag name`. What is missing?

Comment: @user3165438 Compiles fine for me. Did you activate the C++11 mode of the compiler you're using?

Comment: @Loopunrolled, how to do so? I use Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @user3165438 Note that VC++ only [partially supports](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) it in VC10. In VC++, you don't activate the features of a new standard; it automatically works *if possible*.

Comment: so how should I upgrade?

Comment: @user3165438 I suppose you download a newer versions installer and execute it? How did you install VS 2010?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61196/discussion-between-loopunroller-and-user3165438).

Answer (score 8):

Either use

```
Types ty = Double;
```

or

```
enum  class Types {Int,Double,String};  
Types ty = Types::Double;
```

Comment: What is the keyword class in the enum declaration.

Comment: @user3165438 it means so-called scoped enumerations in C++. In fact in some aspects they are equivalent to using enumerations in C#

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is complaining about the attempt at qualifying the value `Double` which is Java's way to do this.

Just do

```
Types ty = Double;
```

Comment: While this is true, I think the problem is more serious than that. I guess he/she is trying to have some enum of "types" and declare variables/fields of that types.

Comment: @gd1 Perhaps. However, that is only a guess since the OP doesn't provide any detail about how this enum is used. Another just as valid guess is that the OP is implementing a compiler and annotating a abstract syntax tree with type information.